# Continuous function between disconnected sets

Tags: general-topology

I’m trying to come up with an example of a continuous function between two disconnected subsets of a set and two disconnected subsets of another set. This is what I’ve got:

*X* = {*x* $\in$ $\mathbb R$ | *x* < 0, *x* > 0}

*Y* = {0, 1}

*f*: *X* $\rightarrow$ *Y*

*P* is the subset of *X* where *x* < 0,

*Q* is the subset of *X* where *x* > 0

*f*(*P*) = 0

*f*(*Q*) = 1

This seems to be continuous because 0 is not part of the domain of the function. Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the topology in $X$ and $Y$ is the topology induced from $\mathbb{R}$. This is correct! When you take the inverse image of $\{0\}$ and $\{1\}$ you get $(-\infty,0)$ and $(0,+\infty),$ respectively, and those are both open sets in $X$.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, this works. You can verify that the inverse image of an open set in the codomain (which is any subset) is open.